# 2 dimentional array is rendered in JS as 1 dimentional array when json_encode is used?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In laravel 8 app I set an array param to blade file, which in Js block is rendered as :

```
slidersAdImageKeys: '{!! json_encode( $slidersAdImageKeys) !!}',
```

But in case I pass array in 1 length , like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ad_id] => 2
            [imageIndex] => 1
            [currentSliderIndex] => 1
            [adImagesLength] => 4
        )
)
```

If source of the file I see that array is rendered as 1 dimentional array.
slidersAdImageKeys:

```
'{"0":{"ad_id":2,"imageIndex":1,"currentSliderIndex":1,"adImagesLength":4}}',
```

json_encode has 2nd flag parameter( https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php ).
Is it some key I need to used to render into 2 dimentional array ?

Thanks!

Comment: `{"0":{"ad_id":2,"imageIndex":1,"currentSliderIndex":1,"adImagesLength":4}}` is not one-dimensional. Notice the two pairs of curly brackets.

Comment: Is your question really about getting an object instead of an array?

Comment: The code and the output doesn't really match though. If you just run `json_encode()` on that array, you should get something like: `[{"ad_id": 2, ....}]`. To get `{"0": {"ad_id": 2, ...}}`, you would need to pass the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag as the second argument to `json_encode()`, which you don't do in the posted code? Or is this one of those "Laravel-things"?

Comment: Lesson of the day: Don't fudge your example code/data, or people on stackoverflow will spend all day repeatedly pointing it out. You can also use `array_values()` to ensure that arrays you want encoded as JSON lists have sequential keys starting at `0`.

Comment: Yes, I really need notan object, but 2-dimensional array. I tried to use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT - but it did not help

Comment: There are no any key like JSON_FORCE_ARRAY?